# Getting undefined on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script which is doing a few equations based on the input values. Everything is working correctly except for the initial display is displaying undefined if no radio buttons have been selected. So if the user just clicks in one of the input fields then the display (bottom table in script) returns an undefined value. But if I click on the radios then it works as expected. I need to keep the initial APR value set to a specific percentage if the user does not do anything but just click in the inputs.

it's a lot of HTML and jQuery so I put the bulk in a fiddle but here is the core script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var updateTotal, currentAPR;

$("body").on("blur", "#vehiclePrice,#estimatedTaxesAndFees,#downPayment,#manufacturerRebate,#tradeInValue,#amtOwedOnTrade,#extendedWarranty,#gapInsurance,#serviceContract", function () {
    updateTotal(currentAPR);
});
updateTotal = function (apr) {
    currentAPR = apr;
    $(".output2").html(apr + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");

    var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
    var input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val()) || 0;
    var input3 = parseInt($('#downPayment').val()) || 0;
    var input4 = parseInt($('#manufacturerRebate').val()) || 0;
    var input5 = parseInt($('#tradeInValue').val()) || 0;
    var input6 = parseInt($('#amtOwedOnTrade').val()) || 0;
    var input7 = parseInt($('#extendedWarranty').val()) || 0;
    var input8 = parseInt($('#gapInsurance').val()) || 0;
    var input9 = parseInt($('#serviceContract').val()) || 0;
    var sum = input1 + input2 - input3 - input4 - input5 + input6 + input7 + input8 + input9;
    $('.total').text('$' + sum.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
    var principle = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
    var apr = $("input[name='status']:checked").attr("apr");
    var months = $("input[name='status']:checked").attr("months");
    var perMonth = sum * (apr / 12) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + (apr / 12)), -months)).toFixed(2);
    $('.perMonth').text('$' + perMonth.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
};
$('label.option').click(function () {
    $('.form-item input[type=radio]').attr('checked', null);
    $('label.option').removeClass("checked").addClass("unchecked");
    $(this).prev().attr('checked', "checked");
    $(this).addClass("checked").removeClass("unchecked");
});

$("input[name='status']").click(function () {
    console.log("changed");
    if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '36') {
        updateTotal("4.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("4.36%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '48') {
        updateTotal("5.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("4.74%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '60') {
        updateTotal("6.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("4.94%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '72') {
        updateTotal("7.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("5.30%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    }
});
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

[Das Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3LcK/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize currentAPR value like this:

```
    var updateTotal, currentAPR = '5.30%';
```

I have put 5.30% since that is the default value you display when the page comes up. Probably it should correspond to the default radio button selection value of '7.95%'.

Comment: You that man... Thank you. Not sure why I did not see that or my numbers off. I will correct it now.